# Rewrite rule for Custom post type Monthly and Yearly archive 

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, rewrite-rules

I have a custom post type "contest_recipe".  I can view contest recipe posts by year and by date with the following urls:

> ```
> http://example.com/2011/?post_type=contest_recipe - shows all 2011 contest recipes
> http://example.com/2011/7/?post_type=contest_recipe - shows all July 2011 contest recipes
> ```

I would like to simplify the url to

> ```
> http://example.com/2011/recipes
> http://example.com/2011/7/recipes
> ```

Is this possible?
I am not familiar with the rewrite rules concept.  Can anyone recommend a tutorial on how to learn about this or provide an example?

Answer (score 3):

I used this to enable yearly and monthly archive for custom post type. Just drop in this code into your `functions.php` file.

This will add your custom rule right on the top of the **Rules array**. NB - Wordpress uses rules array to store rewrite rules.

```
<?php
        function wpse22992_custom_post_rewrite( $rewrite_rules ) {

                $cpslug = 'contest_recipe'; // custom post type slug

                // Rule to display monthly archive -> contest_recipe/2012/08/
                $year_archive = array( $cpslug . '/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/?$' => 'index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&post_type=' . $cpslug );

                // Rule to display yearly archive -> contest_recipe/2012/
                $month_archive = array( $cpslug . '/([0-9]{4})/?$' => 'index.php?year=$matches[1]&post_type=' . $cpslug );

                $rewrite_rules = $year_archive + $month_archive + $rewrite_rules;

                return $rewrite_rules;

        }

        add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'wpse22992_custom_post_rewrite');
?>
```

#### Resource -

- Wordpress Filter - [`rewrite_rules_array`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/rewrite_rules_array)
- Wordpress plugin - [Rewrite Rules Inspector](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/)
   ( Useful to generate even more combinations )