# List Custom Post Types by Date Archive

Tags: custom-post-types, archives, custom-post-type-archives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rewrite rule for Custom post type Monthly and Yearly archive](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22992/rewrite-rule-for-custom-post-type-monthly-and-yearly-archive)

I'm not sure if I'm missing something or what! But I've been trying to get this right for past couple of hours, and I'm in a time crunch.

I have two custom post types, "Photos" and "Videos". All I want to do is have a Month / Year Archive list for each of the post types. So if I'm viewing the content in the "Photos" post type, I want a Month / Year list that contains posts from ONLY the "Photos" post type, and the same goes for video. I'm sure this is possible right?

I'd like to not use a plugin if possible. Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate - [Rewrite rule for Custom post type Monthly and Yearly archive](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/22992/17968)